# how do I retrieve the value of a component without knowing the component's ID or name using javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have two pieces of HTML that were generated by a different member of our team to which I do not have access to editing. My program manager wants me to grab the reference for a case number and to use that in my part of another webpage that is not related to salesforce but is part of the same domain. I have these two pieces of HTML:

```
<records-record-layout-item class="slds-form__item slds-no-space" field-label="Case Number" lwc-2qpe2t0sbck-host="">
<div lwc-2qpe2t0sbck="" class="slds-grid slds-size_1-of-1 label-stacked" data-target-selection-name="sfdc:RecordField.Case.CaseNumber">
<div lwc-2qpe2t0sbck="" class="slds-form-element slds-hint-parent test-id__output-root slds-form-element_readonly is-stacked is-stacked-not-editing">
<div lwc-2qpe2t0sbck="" class="test-id__field-label-container slds-form-element__label no-utility-icon">
<span lwc-2qpe2t0sbck="" class="test-id__field-label">Case Number</span>
</div>
<div lwc-2qpe2t0sbck="" class="slds-form-element__control">
<span lwc-2qpe2t0sbck="" class="test-id__field-value slds-form-element__static slds-grow word-break-ie11 is-read-only">
<slot lwc-2qpe2t0sbck="" name="outputField">
<lightning-formatted-text data-output-element-id="output-field" slot="outputField">03166229</lightning-formatted-text>
</slot>
<slot lwc-2qpe2t0sbck=""></slot>
</span>
```

Second HTML segment:

```
<td role="gridcell" class="slds-cell-edit cellContainer" tabindex="-1" data-aura-rendered-by="55481:0">
<span class="slds-grid slds-grid--align-spread" data-aura-rendered-by="55502:0">
<!--render facet: 55484:0-->
<!--render facet: 55486:0-->
<!--render facet: 55488:0-->
<a data-refid="recordId" data-special-link="true" title="03166229" data-navigable="true" target="_blank" data-ownerid="55482:0" data-recordid="5004v000028mZqIAAU" rel="noreferrer" href="/lightning/r/5004v000028mZqIAAU/view" class="slds-truncate outputLookupLink slds-truncate outputLookupLink-5004v000028mZqIAAU-55482:0 forceOutputLookup" data-aura-rendered-by="55493:0" data-aura-class="forceOutputLookup">03166229<!--render facet: 55496:0-->
</a>
</span>
</td>
```

I need to know how to retrieve the "03166229" value using javascript inside the HTML page.

Comment: Hi, and welcome to SFSE! Without any context, we're not going to be able to answer very easily. Why do you have these HTML fragments, and why do you need the case number from the HTML? What is your actual objective? This may be an [X-Y Problem](https://xyproblem.info/), because there may be another solution if we knew the underlying problem. Also, I invite you to read about [ask] and take our quick [tour]. We'll be happy to answer your question after you [edit] it to include the information we need to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put a reference attribute on the html component

```
lwc:ref="myelement"
```

Then in your javascript controller you can easily reference the value

```
this.refs.myelement.value
```

This is Salesforce's new way of selecting html elements which is easier than using query selectors.

More information can be found on the [Query DOM Elements](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=release-notes.rn_lwc_templaterefs.htm&release=242&type=5) documentation page.

Or, since you already have data attributes (which aren't changed at compile time), you can use a query selector to select the element based on the attribute like

```
this.template.querySelector(`[data-recordid="5004v000028mZqIAAU"]`)
```

And get the value from there.

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for. Thank you!